# How to Skip DataFrame Row via Row Label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to skip summing one specific DataFrame row because  but when I do, I get the `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`.

I know this is a common error, but I have read a number of articles/posts and still haven't been able to figure it out.

The original code is:

```
import os
from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
import pandas as pd

# Set IEX Finance API Token
os.environ['IEX_API_VERSION'] = 'v1'
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'token'

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    symbol = (row["Symbol"])
    company = Stock(symbol, output_format='pandas')
    df_cash_flow = company.get_cash_flow(period="quarter", last='4')
    df_cash_flow['TTM'] = df_cash_flow.sum(axis = 1)
    print(df_cash_flow)
```

And the output is:

```
                    | 6/30/19 | 4/9/19 | 1/5/19 | 10/5/18 | TTM
-----------------------------------------------------------------
capitalExpenditures |   123   |   456  |   789  |   101   | 1469 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
cashChange          |   101   |   633  |   453  |   902   | 2089 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
............
-----------------------------------------------------------------
reportDate          | 6/30/19 | 4/9/19 | 1/5/19 | 10/5/18 |  2019-06-302019-04-09...
-----------------------------------------------------------------
depreciation        |   764   |   122  |   423  |   199   | 1508
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I just want the output to be:

```
                    | 6/30/19 | 4/9/19 | 1/5/19 | 10/5/18 | TTM
-----------------------------------------------------------------
capitalExpenditures |   123   |   456  |   789  |   101   | 1469 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
cashChange          |   101   |   633  |   453  |   902   | 2089 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
............
-----------------------------------------------------------------
reportDate          | 6/30/19 | 4/9/19 | 1/5/19 | 10/5/18 |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
depreciation        |   764   |   122  |   423  |   199   | 1508
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I tried skipping over the `reportDate` row label using `df.loc['reportDate']`:

```
df_cash_flow = company.get_cash_flow(period="quarter", last='4')
    if df_cash_flow.loc['reportDate']:
        pass
    else:
        df_cash_flow['TTM'] = df_cash_flow.sum(axis = 1)
```

but that returns the `ValueError`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A workaround

If the problem is a single cell only, a workaround like just discarding the unwanted result may be acceptable.

Do the sum the way it worked: `df_cash_flow['TTM'] = df_cash_flow.sum(axis = 1)`
Then do:

```
df_cash_flow.loc['reportDate', 'TTM'] = ''
```

This way you are replacing the value in the cell at row `'reportDate'` and column `'TTM'` with an empty string.

#### The proper solution

The proper solution is to select only the desired rows before doing the sum:

```
df_cash_flow['TTM'] = df_cash_flow.loc[df_cash_flow.index.drop('reportDate')].sum(axis=1)
```

By dropping `'reportDate'` from `index`, the sum is performed on the other rows only. You get `NaN` in the cell at row `'reportDate'` and column `'TTM'`.
This solution can be easily expanded to exclude other rows if needed. Just drop all the index labels on which you dont' want to sum, placing them in a list: `df_cash_flow.index.drop(['reportDate', 'otherlabel1', 'otherlabel2'])`